# How to create a custom ListView in Android Studio

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

I'm quite new to Android Studio and for my app I need to create a custom ListView made of cells that have:

- 2x textView
- a non modifiable ratingView (Stars)
- an imageView

the cells should look something like this:

[image: My ListView]

I would really appreciate if you show me a **way to do it using the design interface in Android Studio** instead of the xml editor.

Up until now I created a simple listView but I don't know how to customize it. This is the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="dancam.com.chords.TabMainActivity">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why did I get a -1 ? isn't it a good question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully you can understand and develop your design now.

[image]

Comment: @Sohall could you explain to me what the layout weight is?

Comment: @Daniele layout weight http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-android-s-layout-weight-attribute.html

Comment: @sohall I should implement this design inside the listView right?

Comment: @Daniele yes you can do it if you face any issues we are here to help.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the views for every line.

1. Add a row.xml in your layout resources.
2. Create a custom adapter for listview, in `getView` inflate row.xml.
   Here is an [example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#androidlists_adapterintro).

If you need a more flexible implementation, considere 
using `RecyclerView`, guide [here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-the-RecyclerView).

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll have a look!